# Import a local SQL File To a Remote Server Using SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh, mysql, localhost, tunnel, sql

I have a connection between my localhost and a remote server using putty SSH tunnel.

Thats fine.

Now I need a command to get the sql file on my local machine i.e. c:\folder\test.sql and import it into mysql on the remote server

I thought maybe...

```
mysql -u username -p testpass -h localhost -P 3307 prefix_testdb
```

then do a command like

```
mysql -p -u username database_name < c:\folder\test.sql
```

this command did not work.

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, you need to export your database:

```
mysqldump -p --opt dbname >test.sql
```

Using `SCP`, copy over SSH your file:

```
scp test.sql user@domain:/path/to/test.sql
```

And import it (you need to create dbname before):

```
mysql -p -D dbname <test.sql
```

Comment: I need to use the sql file I already have on my c:\

Comment: Take a look at [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php).

Comment: Silviu suggests to transfer the dump to the remote machine using SCP or WinSCP. Then you login on the machine using SSH, then do the import command.